# Listing available records available to a process in Erlang

Tags: erlang, records

Records are compile time structures. The record_info and is_record recognise the compiled records and their structures. Is there a way to ask the VM what records have been defined that are available to the process? I am interested in getting the internal tuple representation for every record definition.

What I want to do is something like:

-record(car,{make=honda}).

get_record(Car) ->
  %% Some magic here to end up having sth like 
  {car,{make,honda}} or even better #car{} indeed. %% when Car = 'car'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Dynarec (https://github.com/dieswaytoofast/dynarec.git) successfully in a data mapping module for one of the apps I am currently working on.  It is a parse transformer, though, not a run-time VM tool.  It compiles information on each defined record, as well as information about the fields for each record.  In my case, I use it to dynamically map incoming data to record data.  This module may get you what you need.  YMMV.  Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, it does, this is exactly what I am after, yet I wanted to make sure there is no way of getting that without the parse transform. The code of that lib looks really neat. I have a lot of parse transforming going for the logging module - lager anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and how would you do sth like: get_record_name(#car{}) -> car. ?

Comment: In that particular instance, simply look at the first element of the tuple form of the record. #foo{bar = baz} is still represented in code as {foo, baz}.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize I could do {Name,_} = Car.

Answer (score 2):

As you said records are only a compile time construct, so once compiled records are only tuples, this would suggest no available information is left during runtime, but since you mentioned those two functions I was curious and I checked how they worked.

According to [this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id83652)  `record_info/2` is a pseudo function made available only during compilation, so it doesn't need any run time information on records.

On the other hand the description of [`is_record(Term, RecordTag)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_record-2) states that this BIF (built-in function) only *"returns `true` if `Term` is a tuple and its first element is `RecordTag`, `false` otherwise"*, so it is actually only checking the structure and first element of the tuple.

Based on this, I would guess that there is no record information made available during runtime. [This thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-January/024666.html) confirms the unavailability of record_info/2 during runtime.

Comment: `record_info/2` is __created__ automatically during compilation, and it is accessible at any time, during run time especially. According to [documentation you are pointing to](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id83652).

Comment: @mpm I don't see where the documentation I pointed to says `record_info/2` is available during runtime.You check this just by calling `Module:module_info(functions)` in a module where there's a record defined, you will see no `record_info/2` defined.

Comment: @mpm Please check [this thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-January/024666.html) that confirms the unavailability of `record_info/2` during runtime.

Comment: I stand corrected. Somehow I must confused what `record_info/2` could do with `rr` function in shell (which is somewhat magical place [and manages to do it from time to time](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl#L1212) ). If you add any edits to your answer, I will be able to remove "vote down".

Answer (score 1):

As others have said records are purely compile time and there is no runtime information about records. Erlang just sees tuples. For example the `record_info/2` pseudo functions are expanded to data at compile time, a list of atoms for `fields` argument and an integer for `size`.